# Jquery Slider, Default Value on Load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, uislider

I have one Jquery slider with 4 step and its value is 0, 1, 3 and 3.
Alert code working fine when I slide. but my issue is I want to alert default slider value "0" when page load.

So in below example, when page load. page should alert "0". which is default value of slider and place in else.

**Here is my JQ Code and [Fiddle is Here](http://jsfiddle.net/2mpFw/)**

```
$(function () {
    $("#slider").slider({
        value: 0,
        min: 0,
        max: 3,
        step: 1,
        orientation: "horizontal",
        range: "min",
        animate: true,
        slide: function (event, ui) {
            console.log(ui.value);
            if (ui.value == 0) {
                alert(ui.value);
            } else if (ui.value == 1) {
                alert(ui.value);
            } else if (ui.value == 2) {
                alert(ui.value);
            } else {
                alert(ui.value);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this:

```
 //TO DEFINE SLIDER AND EVENTS
 $('#slider').slider().bind('slidechange',function(event,ui){
 console.log(ui.value);
        if (ui.value == 0) {
            alert(ui.value);
        } else if (ui.value == 1) {
            alert(ui.value);
        } else if (ui.value == 2) {
            alert(ui.value);
        } else {
            alert(ui.value);
        }

 });

 //TO TRIGGER EVENT
 $('#slider').trigger('slidechange');
```

Comment: Not Working,
I want that when page load, slider's value '0' should alert without slide.

Answer (score 0):

When the page loads, the slide function is not being triggered right away. Why not just add a single alert after the creation of the slider? This works for me in Fiddle:

```
$(function () {
    // Create slider
    $("#slider").slider({
        ... your code ...
    });

    // alert initial slider value
    alert($("#slider").slider('value'));
});
```

Comment: Can you please provide me an example ?